# gitbook: how to convert emoji short codes in markdown so they are correctly imported as emojis in gitbook (cloud)

Tags: unicode, emoji, gitbook

I'm not sure if this counts as a programming question but I'll give it a go and hope I'm not shot down in flames.

I have a lot of markdown content that contains emoji short code references. I have imported a repo from github into gitbook and all those references are appearing as the raw text instead of the emoji. I believe gitbook can handle emojis but the only information I can find just relates to being able to type in an emoji whilst editing a page in gitbook. I am not going to manually change all those (probably hundreds) of emojis by hand, so I need to be able to convert the emojis in the source repo so they can be resynced back to gitbook.

So what is the correct format of an emoji so that when it is imported into gitbook at appears correctly?

There is a [github emoji api](https://api.github.com/emojis) which I intend to make use of to create a PowerShell function that maps the short code to whatever format the gitbook understands. All I need to know is, what is that format? Is it the unicode code (perhaps 0x1f1e6 for example)? I know that gitbook is quite limited in it's functionality, can't do custom CSS and they openly admit that fragments of HTML simply just won't work. Once I have this, I can run it against all the markdown in my git repos. I'm hoping that once I remap the short codes, it will still be in a format that is compatible with markdown so it's still correctly visible as an emoji when viewing from github.

Comment: Why not just convert to the short codes to their corresponding Unicode characters? Then you won't have to worry about what short code format is supported in gitbook --- or whatever content management system you migrate to in the future.

Comment: @PeterConstable Well yeah you got it, that's the entire point of my question. I have just discovered that the format that I needed to know about is this: &#x[unicode code point];